# Twitter json output

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter

```
$(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=user_name&callback=?',
                //dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){$('body').append('the data is' +data);}
            });
            });
```

the above code with dataType line prints out [objects] while with the dataType line commented  it prints out nothing ...how can i get it to print the json output from the server rather then the javascript object?

Comment: Do you just want to inspect it or...? Without it being JSON (JSONP actually) you can't make the cross-domain request, so no option there, but are you just trying to view the object to see what properties you need?

Comment: @Nick yeah i just want to inspect it .

Comment: @Bunny - Just visit: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=user_name&callback=? and you can view the object :) or `console.log(data)`, what you're after is probably `data[0].user.description` or something.

Comment: yeah that was useful but a console.log(data) shows an empty string.

Comment: @Bunny - You need the `dataType` in there, is it still commented out?

Comment: @Nick yeah got it .. and is there a way to indent the one liner at http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=user_name&callback=

Comment: @Bunny - Paste the result at: http://www.jsonlint.com/ and hit validate :) Formatting's a side-benefit there

Comment: @Bunny - I added all that into a complete answer, with some links I think you'll find handy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to check out [Twitter's API docs](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation), it has all this broken down with descriptions, [here's the direct link to `user_timeline`](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-user_timeline).

Alternatively, here's the manual route :)
To inspect it you have a few options, if you're using Firefox/Firebug or Chrome, you can log it to the console, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=user_name&callback=?',
  dataType:'json',
  success:function(data){ console.log(data); }
});
```

Another option is just visiting the URL: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=user_name&callback= Then take the result and pop it in [something like JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to format it for easier browsing.

What you'll probably end up wanting is something like this:

```
data[0].user.friends_count
```

Answer (score 1):

hope you are using firebug,

add this to your code:

```
success:function(data){console.log(data);}
```

check the firebug console to see what data object has. Acccordingly use the object like

```
success:function(data){$('body').append('the data is' +data.key);}
```

Or use this short hand for getting json encoded data

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  $('.result').html('<p>' + data.foo + '</p>'
    + '<p>' + data.baz[1] + '</p>');
});
```

more info at [getJSONdocumentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: You would need to append `?jsoncallback=?` to your `getJSON` example, since this is a cross-domain situation there are other factors at play.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
success:function(data){$('body').append('the data is' +data.urKeyname);}
```